# Sorting is very slow if sort order is explicitly defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sorting

As you can check in the code below, defining a sort order by prefixing the property name with a `+` or `-` results in a drastically slower sort. Any ideas why?

Default Sort (value): `5.84ms`

Ascending Sort (+value): `58.59ms`

Descending Sort (-value): `49.28ms`

The fact that there is a difference between `value` and `+value` (Which both return the exact same sort order) is very confusing to me.

```js
let arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  arr.push({ _id: 'doc' + i, value: Math.random(), k: i % 20 })
}

function sort (...keys) {
  let data = {}
  data.sort = []
  keys.forEach(key => {
    const newKey = key.replace(/(\-|\+)/g, '')
    const order = key[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1
    data.sort.push({
      key: newKey,
      order: order
    })
  })
  return data
}

function compare (sortData, a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < sortData.length; ++i) {
    const data = sortData[i]
    const _a = a[data.key]
    const _b = b[data.key]
    if (_a !== _b) return _a > _b ? data.order : -data.order
  }
  return 0
}

function exec (data) {
  let r = arr.slice()
  if (data.sort) {
    r.sort((a, b) => {
      let r = compare(data.sort, a, b)
      return r
    })
  }
  return r
}

function time (f) {
  let start = performance.now()
  f()
  return performance.now() - start
}

function test (f, n) {
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) total += time(f)
  return total / n
}

const q1 = sort('value')
const q2 = sort('+value')
const q3 = sort('-value')
const sortDefault = () => exec(q1)
const sortAsc = () => exec(q2)
const sortDesc = () => exec(q3)

console.log('    Default Sort (value):', test(sortDefault, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log(' Ascending Sort (+value):', test(sortAsc, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('Descending Sort (-value):', test(sortDesc, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
```

Comment: not sure on the performance difference, but that's a strange way of writing a comparator in JS.   It would be more usual to write a function that _returns_ a function that is then passed to `Array.prototype.sort`.

Comment: It's around the same time for me:
`Default Sort (value): 6.60ms
Ascending Sort (+value): 9.45ms
Descending Sort (-value): 7.39ms`

Comment: How odd, I too get the same rough times in Firefox, but IE/Edge/Chrome/NodeJS all are resulting in increased times.

Comment: Same here with Node JS, even though the resulting sort parameters are identical, and irrespective of which order I run the three tests.

Comment: Chrome is where the largest difference seems to be. Just a guess, but I think it has to do with breaking optimizations in field access, where they were able to statically determine that `"value"` is never altered by the `key.replace(/(\-|\+)/g, '')`, so they're able to use their low level class representation but with the others it defaults to a hash table representation of the object. Accessing keys via `[...]` can do that when their engine is unable to statically determine the value of the expression.

Comment: Yes I originally thought it may be a Chrome/V8 optimization issue. Best solution is to forget the fancy `+`/`-` prefix of properties and just pass that seperately `sort('value',1)` etc.?

Comment: If this is performance critical, then finding a way other than encoding the order into the key may not be a bad idea.

Comment: yeah, it's definitely something to do with parsing the sort order strings.

Comment: this is really weird. I got same result in Chrome(4.76 vs. 40.24 vs 40.79) but got fairly similar performance in Firefox (4.36 vs. 5.41 vs 5.63). I will follow up with this question and let's see who can figure out the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more usual to write a function that *returns* a comparator, although in this case it appears that the performance differences are down to how the V8 JS engine optimises the code in the case where the regular expression was matched.

A more canonical usage therefore might be:

```
function buildSort(...keys) {

  if (typeof keys[0] === "string") {
    keys = keys.map(key => {
        const order = key[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1
        key = key.replace(/(\-|\+)/g, '')
        return { key, order };
    })
  }

  return (a, b) => {
    for (let { key, order } of keys ) {
      const _a = a[key];
      const _b = b[key];
      if (_a !== _b) return _a > _b ? order : -order
    }
    return 0
  }
}

function exec(comparator) {
  return arr.slice().sort(comparator);
}

...

const q1 = buildSort({ key: 'value', order: 1 });
const q2 = buildSort({ key: 'value', order: -1 });
const q3 = buildSort('+value')
```

On my laptop running NodeJS 6.9.1 passing `{ key: 'value', order: 1 }` or `"value"` gives a runtime of 0.015 seconds, whereas passing `"+value"` runs in 0.46 seconds even though nominally these result in the same values appearing in the `keys` structure being used within the comparator.

Answer (score 1):

This is meant more as a comment, but is too long for one: for a test scenario to see if there was a V8 performance difference if the key was interned later, I tried storing a raw key (the result of the regex) and getting the actual key of the object on the first comparison (which theoretically should be an interned or at least optimizable string).

Below is the same code, but a property `rawkey` is set instead of 'key' inside the sort function and the key is obtained inside compare with `if(!data.key) data.key = Object.keys(a).filter(k=>k==data.rawkey)[0];`
For better or for worse, that created in the same performance over the board for me in Chrome.
The implementation is just a show case and not safe it not all objects might have the actual properties

```js
let arr = []

for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  arr.push({ _id: 'doc' + i, value: Math.random(), k: i % 20 })
}

function sort (...keys) {
  let data = {}
  data.sort = []
  keys.forEach(key => {
    const newKey = key.replace(/(\-|\+)/g, '')
    const order = key[0] === '-' ? -1 : 1
    data.sort.push({
      rawkey: newKey,
      order: order
    })
  })
  return data
}

function compare (sortData, a, b) {
  for (let i = 0; i < sortData.length; ++i) {
    const data = sortData[i];
    if(!data.key) data.key = Object.keys(a).filter(k=>k==data.rawkey)[0];
    const _a = a[data.key]
    const _b = b[data.key]
    if (_a !== _b) return _a > _b ? data.order : -data.order
  }
  return 0
}

function exec (data) {
  let r = arr.slice()
  if (data.sort) {
    r.sort((a, b) => {
      let r = compare(data.sort, a, b)
      return r
    })
  }
  return r
}

function time (f) {
  let start = performance.now()
  f()
  return performance.now() - start
}

function test (f, n) {
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) total += time(f)
  return total / n
}

const q1 = sort('value')
const q2 = sort('+value')
const q3 = sort('-value')
const sortDefault = () => exec(q1)
const sortAsc = () => exec(q2)
const sortDesc = () => exec(q3)

console.log('    Default Sort (value):', test(sortDefault, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log(' Ascending Sort (+value):', test(sortAsc, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('Descending Sort (-value):', test(sortDesc, 10).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
```

Comment: FWIW, as an "extended comment" you could do as I did and make this "Community Wiki".  It's also unclear exactly what your `Object.keys()` code is actually doing to the optimizer under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that dynamically building the comparison function avoids the slowdown, and is actually much faster in almost all cases in my (albeit minimal) testing.

```
      Default ( value): 5.47ms
      Default (+value): 54.17ms
      Default (-value): 51.90ms
eval Function ( value): 3.25ms
eval Function (+value): 3.51ms
eval Function (-value): 2.99ms
```

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
  let o = { _id: 'doc' + i, value: Math.random() }
  arr.push(o)
}

function sortKeys (...keys) {
  const data = {}
  data.sort = []
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (typeof key === 'string') key = getSortObject(key)
    if (key.order === undefined) key.order = 1
    data.sort.push(key)
  })
  return data
}

function getSortObject (str) {
  if (str.match(/^(\+|\-)/)) {
    return { key: str.substr(1), order: -1 }
  } else {
    return { key: str, order: 1 }
  }
}

function exec (data, compFn) {
  let r = arr.slice()
  if (data.sort) {
    r.sort(compFn(data.sort))
  }
  return r
}

// Old comparator, seems to cause optimization problems in the V8 engine. (Chrome/NodeJS/etc.)
function comparison (sdata) {
  return function (a, b) {
    for (let i = 0; i < sdata.length; ++i) {
      const data = sdata[i]
      const _a = a[data.key]
      const _b = b[data.key]
      if (_a !== _b) return _a > _b ? data.order : -data.order
    }
    return 0
  }
}

// Builds a function from the sort keys.
function getCompFunc (sortData) {
  let str = ''
  sortData.forEach(sort => {
    str += `if(a.${sort.key}${sort.order === 1 ? '>' : '<'}b.${sort.key})return 1;`
    str += `if(a.${sort.key}${sort.order === 1 ? '<' : '>'}b.${sort.key})return -1;`
  })
  str += `return 0;`
  return Function('a', 'b', str)
}

function time (f) {
  let start = performance.now()
  f()
  return performance.now() - start
}

function test (f, n) {
  let total = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) total += time(f)
  return total / n
}

const q1 = sortKeys('value')
const q2 = sortKeys('+value')
const q3 = sortKeys('-value')
const sortDefault = () => exec(q1, comparison)
const sortAsc = () => exec(q2, comparison)
const sortDesc = () => exec(q3, comparison)
const sortDefaultEval = () => exec(q1, getCompFunc)
const sortAscEval = () => exec(q2, getCompFunc)
const sortDescEval = () => exec(q3, getCompFunc)

console.log('A:', test(sortDefault, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('B:', test(sortAsc, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('C:', test(sortDesc, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('-')
console.log('D:', test(sortDefaultEval, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('E:', test(sortAscEval, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
console.log('F:', test(sortDescEval, 5).toFixed(2) + 'ms')
```